# Update a single value in a database table through form submission

Tags: postgresql, playframework

Here is my table in the database :

```
 id  | account_name | account_number | account_type | address |            email             | ifsc_code | is_default_account |  phone_num  | User
-----+--------------+----------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+----------
 201 | helloi32irn  | 55265766432454 | Savings      |         | mypal.appa99721989@gmail.com | 5545      | f                  | 98654567876 | abc
 195 | hello        | 55265766435523 | Savings      |         | mypal.1989@gmail.com         | 5545      | t                  | 98654567876 | axyz
 203 | what         | 01010101010101 | Current      |         | guillaume@sample.com         | 6123      | f                  | 09099990    | abc
```

On form submission in the view, which only posts a single parameter which in my case is  name= "activate" which corresponds to the column "is_default_account" in the table. 
I want to change the value of "is_default_account" from "t" to "f". For example here in the table, for account_name "hello" it is "t". And i want to deactivate it, i.e make it "f" and activate any of the other that has been sent trough the form

Answer (score 1):

This will update your table and make account 'what' default (assuming that is_default_account is BOOLEAN field):

```
UPDATE table
SET is_default_account = (account_name = 'what')
```

You may want limit updates if table is more than just few rows you listed, like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET is_default_account = (account_name = 'what')
WHERE is_default_account != (account_name = 'what')
  AND <limit updates by some other criteria like user name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to accomplish what you want to do you should send at least two values from the form. One for the id of the account you want to update and the other for the action (activate here). You can also just send the id and have it toggle. There are many ways to do this but I can't figure out exactly what you are trying to do and whether you want SQL or Playframework code. Without limiting your update in somewhere (like id) you can't precisely control what specific rows get updated. Please clarify your question and add some more code if you want help on the playframework side, which I would think you do.

Comment: Bladmiral, I need the Playframework code, i.e the controller to accomplish it.